# shorthand if/else variable exists

Tags: javascript, shorthand, shorthand-if

I'm simply running a function which checks if the variable `year` is set if not then set it `new Date().getFullYear()`.

The error I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: year is not defined

```
year = (year) ? year : new Date().getFullYear();
console.log(year);
```

Why can't I check if `year` exists and if not set it?

Comment: where do you get `year` from?

Comment: Try putting `var` in front of it.

Comment: The variable `year` must be declared before the ternary shorthand.

Comment: @Pointy yea it will work if I put `var` but I want it to be a global

Comment: try `window.year = ...`

Comment: Then do `window.year = year || new Date().getFullYear();`

Comment: @WillP. that did the trick thanks.

Comment: @Pointy thanks yea that did the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`year = year || new Date().getFullYear();`

Useful to check function parameters

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: year is not defined`

Answer (score 6):

```
year = year ?? new Date().getFullYear();
```

another way

Comment: This should be the correct answer. In @Wainage's example, if 'year' was defined, but as a `false` boolean, it would still return the RHS operand (that's not really checking if the variable exists or not), where as with the `Nullish coalescing operator` '??', you would set `year` to be false in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object Notation:

```
// In the global scope window is this
this['year'] = this['year'] ? year : (new Date).getFullYear();
console.log(year);
```

or perhaps better use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Ftypeof)

```
year = (typeof year === "undefined") ? (new Date()).getFullYear() : year
```

Comment: where is `this` coming from?

Comment: There is always a `this`

Comment: but not in functions with strict mode. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context

Comment: Pedatic, this question dealing with assigning variables that are not already defined removes the possibility of strict mode.